# Built-in cursor function for getting no of rows affected

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

This is an update function that I have created. It works fine, but I want to know where can we use any function that will let us know that number of rows affected. For example in Oracle we do have `rowcount()` function.

```
int updatestatus(String email) {
    int up = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("update " + logintable + " set " + flag +" = 1  where " + UID + " = " + email ,null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    up = 1;
    return up;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("YOUR_COLUMN", "newValue");

int RowsUpdated = db.update("YOUR_TABLE", newValues, "id=6", null);
```

Here RowsUpdated will return number of rows affected with your query.

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: don't we have any built in function with cursor?

Comment: db.update() is inbuilt function that return on of rows affected.